# Minecraft Java on Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

My niece would like to play Minecraft with me, but I have/play on Java only and her laptop's operating system is Windows 10, are you able to get the Java edition of Minecraft on Windows 10 or can it only get the Windows 10 edition of Minecraft?

Answer (score 4):

You are able to get Minecraft Java edition on Windows 10. Just go [here](https://minecraft.net) and follow your usual procedures to buy Minecraft. In the future, please try to first research on this site first before asking your question, as this question seems to be a duplicate.